# Prolog Sum value numbers smaller than limit

Tags: prolog

Define predicate summy(List, Limit, N), where List is a list of absolute value numbers, and N is the sum of such numbers from List lists whose value is smaller than Limit.

This is what I have:
*

```
abx([],[]).
abx([H|T], [H|T1]):-
    H >= 0,!,
    abx(T,T1).
abx([M|T], [M1|T1]):-
    M < 0,
    M1 is M * (-1),
    abx(T,T1).

summy([], [], []).
summy([H|T], L, N):-
    abx([H|T], [X|Y]),
     X < L,
    sumlist([X|Y], N).
```

- 

If I run the example it shows X=26, not X=11.

Comment: What did you try, what is not working with that?

Comment: I have got problem with that the X < L, not working and if I run the example it shows X=26 (the right answer is X=11).

Comment: well you are only filtering the "first" item. In case `X < L`, it will sum the entire list. If not, the predicate will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filtering part is wrong. The `X < L` will check if `X`, the first element of the list is less than `L`. If it is, it will calculate the sum of all absolute values, if it is not, the entire predicate will fail.

You should thus filter, for example with:

```
filterless([], L, []).
filterless([H|T], L, [H|T2]) :-
    H < L,
    filterless(T, L, T2).
filterless([H|T], L, T2) :-
    H > L,
    filterless(T, L, T2).
```

Then the summary is thus:

```
summy(Xs, L, R) :-
    abx(Xs, As),
    filterless(As, L, Bs),
    sumlist(Bs, R).
```

We can however make use of [**`maplist/3`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3) to do a mapping, and [**`include/3`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=include/3) to filter the list, so we can rewrite `summy/3` to:

```
summy(Xs, L, R) :-
    maplist(abs, Xs, As),
    include(>(L), As, Bs),
    sumlist(Bs, R).
```

Comment: Woow I didn't know about the maplist/3 and include/3. Thank you very much, you are the Genius.